# Total possible combinations of variables

Tags: permutations, combinations

I have 4 factors, each containing a different number of entry.

For example:

[image]

I would like to list and compute the number of possible combinations. So each combination consist of 1 fruit, 1 drink, 1 burger, 1 location.

The first combination is -> orange, coffee, cheese, bar
The last combination is -> banana, rootbeer, ham, kitchen

The order does not matter. Is there any general equation that can compute the number of all possible combinations?

UPDATE ON QUESTION:

Currently, the multiplication rule is used to form combinations that take in all factors.

What if I would like to find, the total number of combinations that uses all factors, 3 factors and a minimum of 2 factors?

All factors = Fruit, Drink, Burger, Location
3 factors = e.g. Fruit, drink, burger ; Fruit Burger location; etc.
2 factors = e.g. Fruit, drink; Burger, location; etc.

How could I compute this?

Comment: Apply multiplication principle.  There will be $4\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 7$ possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) states that if there are $m$ ways of performing a task and a second task can be performed independently of the first in $n$ ways, then the number of ways of performing both tasks is $mn$.

For each of the four ways a fruit can be selected, a drink can be selected in six ways.  Thus, there are $4 \cdot 6 = 24$ ways of selecting a fruit and a drink as you can check by drawing a tree diagram.

For each of the $24$ ways a fruit and a drink can be selected, a burger can be selected in five ways.  Hence, there are $24 \cdot 5 = 120$ ways of selecting a fruit, drink, and burger.

For each of the $120$ ways of selecting a fruit, drink, and burger, the location can be selected in seven ways, yielding $120 \cdot 7 = 840$ ways of selecting a fruit, drink, burger, and location.

Notice, as JMoravitz pointed out in the comments, that the number of ways of performing all four tasks is $4 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 = 840$.

Comment: I see! A clear and concise explanation indeed. Thank you very much Taussig and JMoravitz

Comment: Currently, the multiplication rule is used to form combinations that take in all factors. 

What if I would like to find, the total number of combinations that uses all factors, 3 factors and a minimum of 2 factors? 

All factors = Fruit, Drink, Burger, Location
3 factors = e.g. Fruit, drink, burger ; Fruit Burger location; etc.
2 factors = e.g. Fruit, drink; Burger, location; etc.

How could I compute this?

Comment: If you wish to find the total number of combinations of three factors, apply the Multiplication Principle to fruit, drink, burger; fruit, drink, location; fruit, burger, location; and drink, burger, location.  Once you have those results, you can add the separate cases since they are mutually exclusive.  When events are mutually exclusive, we use the [Addition Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum).    The case of two types is handled similarly.  Apply the Multiplication Principle to each of the six pairs, then use the Addition Principle to sum the results.

Comment: say, if I have more factors than 4, I would have to compute each possible combination manually right? If I need only 3 factors out of 4, then I would compute the totaly number of combinations for each combination and sum

Comment: That is correct.  In this case, the number of ways of selecting objects from three of the four categories is $$4 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 + 4 \cdot 6 \cdot 7 + 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 + 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 = 120 + 168 + 140 + 210 = 638$$